# RFID identify and send to mobile app

Tags: rfid, nfc

I am planning to make a device and a mobile app with RFID.

Main objective is,

1. There will be set of square blocks(5), each block can contain RFID, each denotes a number.
2. I will have a placeholder tray for putting these square blocks (lets' say you can place 5)
3. when the block is placed on a tray, i need to know which block was placed there and which position on the tray
4. send these signals/beacons to the app and app will do further based on the positions.

can this be achieved with RFID/NFC ?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what communicates with what, especially on the mobile phone side.

But if you expect the mobile to communicate with the trays/blocks located 10-30cm away through RFID/NFC, answer is no (Bluetooth would be an option, though).

And if you expect RFID/NFC technology to be able to precisely tell the position of a given block within a tray, answer is also no. RFID/NFC will only make it possible for a block (acting as a NFC tag) to indicate its presence within a tray (acting as a NFC reader), but it won't tell you where in the tray. For this, I don't see any easy solution, actually. A camera + image processing is an option, but not trivial to implement.